# What bit-level-changes are made while typecasting a float 32bit variable to unsigned integer 32bit?

Tags: c++, c

Consider I want to typecast float 32 bit data to an unsigned integer 32 bit.

```
float foo = 5.0f;  
uint32 goo;
goo = (uint32)foo;
```

How does the compiler typecast a variable? Is there any intermediate steps; and if yes what are they?

Comment: The compiler has to do whatever it takes to implement the language requirements (i.e. truncate the fractional parts off and produce the value 5).

Comment: And this will almost certainly be implemented in hardware, not by the compiler, except insofar as it invokes the correct FPU instruction. Unclear *why* you're asking.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: @EJP: "And this will almost certainly be implemented in hardware" - for most existing architectures this is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf :Can you pls explain how it is different in c and c++. I am curious as I am developing in both platforms.

Comment: @Olaf: are C and C++ really different as far as this question goes?

Comment: C++ provides a plethora of typecasts. And details might differ, too for this cast. Just compare the standards.

Comment: @Olaf: The question is asking about a C-style cast. A C-style cast is the same in both languages, and that's no accident.

Comment: @Olaf This is wrong how? Such FPU instructions don't exist?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Possibly not for this cast, but the question seems to target more for a `reinterpret_cast` behaviour.

Comment: @EJP: Where did I write an FPU does not have such an instructuion? Maybe I should have highlighted "**almost certainly**". Most architectures don't even have a FPU.

Comment: On x86 architecture, the FIST instruction stores a floating point register as an integer to memory.

Comment: @Olaf With one single exception, every architecture I have ever used since 1971 has had an FPU.

Comment: @EJP: So you never programmed an embedded CPU: 8051, PIC16, MSP430, HC05/08/11/12/16, ARM7, ARM Cortex-M0/3/4, ColdFire, some 68K, C166 and a lot of others. They very likely outnumber the architectures with an FPU by units sold (some decades), but also by architectures.

Comment: Let's not forget the Z80

Comment: @Olaf gcc targeting armv7 generates `ftouizs s0, s0` for this operation. I think armv7 CPUs typically have onboard VFP

Comment: @M.M: How yould I have forget this? And the 6502. But I tried to concentrate on architectures still in wider use. Maybe the Z8 or some drivates are still used. Then there are DSPs and FPGA-integrated CPUs.

Comment: @M.M: `ARM7 != ARMv7`! And Cortext-M3/4/7 are also ARMv7! You mean  ARMv7A, not sure if the Cortex-R (ARMv7R) always has an FPU.

Comment: @Olaf That's correct, I didn't, but I consider my experience both long enough and various enough to be representative. 'Almost certainly' would definitely apply to it and to the experience of most senior people I know.

Comment: @EJP: Well, you don't know me and the seniors I know apparently. It is always problematic to make an absolute statement for a language supporting that many different architectures (and different scales) like C. Server, PC and mobile CPUs make just a very small set of the architectures. Even your PC and mobile possibly include more CPUs without FPU than with. Not to mentionm your fridge, washing-machine, car (some 10 CPUs, even for small cars), etc.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't make an absolute statement. I made a relative statement. 'Almost certainly'. I haven't programmed a washing machine, and the probabilities are overwhelming against the OP having done so either.

Comment: @EJP: "Almost certainly" is quite clear on the absolute side than other phrases. And just that I corrected. I don't make assumptions about what OP programs for. Could be very well an Arduino (AVR - no FPU) or any other school/university/maker project.

Comment: @Olaf 'Almost certainly' is not an absolute statement. Period. I'm having trouble making sense of this discussion. First you deny having said there is no such instruction, and then the rest of your posts rely on there being no FPU at all. As to what the OP is using, there is zero evidence.

Comment: @EJP: However one might read my first comment (there is no FPU, or there is no hardware-support on most architectures), not having a FPU implies there is no hardware-support to convert a float to an integer. And It was not me assuming OP has a specific hardware available. I clearly did not even comment on that. Apparently I cannot make you understand my point - either because I don't find the correct wording or you refuse to follow my arguments. So I'll leave it at that. Feel free to have the last word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to depend on the hardware to a large degree (though things like the OS/compiler can and will change how the hardware is used).

For example, on older Intel processors (and current ones, in most 32-bit code) you use the x87 instruction set for (most) floating point. In this case, there's an `fistp` (floating point integer store and pop, though there's also a non-popping variety, in case you also need to continue using that floating point value) that supports storing to an integer, so that's what's typically used. There's a bit in the floating point control word that controls how that conversion will be done (rounding versus truncating) that has to be set correctly as well.

On current hardware (with a current compiler producing 64-bit code) you're typically going to be using SSE instructions, in which case conversion to a signed int can be done with cvtss2si.

Neither of these directly supports unsigned operands though (at least I'm sure SSE doesn't, and to the best of my recollection x87 doesn't either). For these, the compiler probably has a small function in the library, so it's done (at least partly) in software.

If your compiler supports generating AVX256/AVX512 instructions, it could use VCVTTSS2USI to convert from 32-bit float to 64-bit integer, then store the bottom 32-bits of that integer to your destination (and if the result was negative or too large to fit in a 32-bit integer, well...the standard says that gives undefined behavior, so you got what you deserved).

Comment: Not sure about C++, but the C standard is quite exact how to convert a float to an integer, as long the integer can represent the resulting value, of course.

Comment: @Olaf: Both require truncation, which works out to "round toward zero" (i.e., round negative numbers up, and positive numbers down). Most hardware (certainly including Intel and compatible) includes a mode to do precisely that.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point and unsigned numbers are stored in completely different formats, so the compiler must change from one to the other, as opposed to casting from unsigned to signed where the format of the number is the same and the software just changes how the number is interpreted.

For example, in 32 bit floats the number 5 is represented as 0x40a00000 in float, and 0x00000005 as an unsigned.

This conversion ends up being significant when you're working with weaker microcontrollers, on anything with a FPU it is a few extra instructions.

[Here is the wikipedia write up on floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

[Here is a floating point converter that shows the bit level data](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will take care of this part, for example on Intel architecture with the SSE FPU support, GCC defined some operation in "[emmtrin.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bd3f0a53c07086e978ea4ec00e10a20e4a969c40/gcc/config/i386/emmintrin.h)"

A simple way to figure out is just compile a small c program with assembly output, you will get something like:

```
 movss -4(%rbp), %xmm0
 cvtps2pd  %xmm0, %xmm0
 movsd .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
 addsd %xmm1, %xmm0
 cvttsd2si %xmm0, %eax
```

The FPU related instructions (***cvtps2pd/[cvttsd2si](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTSD2SI.html)***) is used here, this exactly depends on target machine.